# Insert jsp form to database using spring boot

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm a beginner in spring boot I start with creating a contact form that send data to data base. this is the form:

```
<form:form method="POST" id="contactform" modelAttribute="message">
            <div class="form">
                <div class="six columns noleftmargin">
                <label name="name">Name</label>
                <form:input path="name" type="text"  class="smoothborder" placeholder="Your name *"/>
                </div>
                <div class="six columns">
                <label name="email">E-mail address</label>
                <form:input path="email" type="text"  class="smoothborder" placeholder="Your e-mail address *"/>
                </div>
                <label name="comment">Message</label>
                <form:textarea path="comment" class="smoothborder ctextarea" rows="14" placeholder="Message, feedback, comments *"></form:textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" class="readmore" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
            </form:form>
```

And this is my conact controller:

```
 @Autowired
  private MessageRepository messageRepository ;

  @RequestMapping(value= "/newmessage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String newMessage(ModelMap model) {
     Message message = new Message();
     model.addAttribute("message", message);
      return  ("/contact");
    }

  @RequestMapping(value="/newmessage",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String saveMessage( Message message, BindingResult result, ModelMap model)
  {

      if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "/contact";
        }

      messageRepository.save(message);
      model.addAttribute("success", "Message " + message.getName() + " "+ message.getEmail() + " "+ message.getComment()+ " registered successfully");
        //return "success";
        return "/homepage";
```

Folder Structure

[image: Folder Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the action of the form. If you want to hit `/newmessage` while submitting form, then you need to change as following :

```
<form:form method="POST" id="contactform" action="/newmessage" modelAttribute="message">
     <!-- The elements of the form -->
</form:form>
```

Also, you need to add the `modelAttribute` to your controller method. And you should return only the name of the `jsp` page. If your page name is `homepage.jsp` then you should only return `homepage` from your controller method. Of course, `homepage.jsp` file needs to be in `WEB-INF` folder.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/newmessage",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveMessage(@ModelAttribute("message") Message message, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
    // Rest of the code

    return "homepage";
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry but same error still exist, my views are placed in src/main/web app because  it search there for views and not in resources/templates. i added all jsp dependencies

Comment: your views should be placed in ` src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` folder

Comment: i'm using sts tools,i create new spring starter project, by default  there's no WEB-INF under webapp should i add it by my self?(am sorry for my questions i'm a beginner )

Comment: Are you using default spring format. Would you please share the `servlet.xml` and spring configuration java file. You can share the folder structure

Comment: Does't your project have `web.xml` file ?

Comment: i just add my folder structure please check it

Comment: it's a spring boot project so there's no configuration files

Comment: Is there any `.properties` file in resources folder ?

Comment: yeaa it's application.properties:   i'll added in main problem

Comment: Ok fine. Then would you please follow the official example of spring boot  ? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp

Comment: Add an extra line : `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/` in `application.properties` file. Then put your `homepage.jsp` under `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp` folder

Comment: I think there will be `WEB-INF` folder under `src`(above `target` folder in your picture) .

Comment: by default it's src/main/webapp/ but is this the problem of the error? i'm putting my views in the wrong places!? it seems like the app search here for views and not in other places

Comment: Yup, you are putting your views in wrong places. Correct the folder structure and follow my code. You will be succeeded.